# Reading Clob object using getCharacterStream API causes "java.sql.SQLException: could not reset reader"

Tags: java, hibernate, clob

I am using Hibernate 3.6.10 version and trying to read a Clob data type after saving a record (Student). It is throwing error "could not reset reader"

```
 public class Student implements java.io.Serializable {

    private long studentId;
    private String studentName;
    private Address studentAddress;
    private Clob searchProfileText;
```

While testing ... first I am saving a Student record then trying to get the searchProfileText from that record again as followiing

```
1        student1.setSearchProfileText(clob);
2       session.save(student1);
3        System.out.println("Reading Clob : " + student1.getSearchProfileText().getCharacterStream());
```

Line number 3 , I am getting following exception

```
java.sql.SQLException: could not reset reader
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.ClobProxy.resetIfNeeded(ClobProxy.java:178)
```

I tried `session.flush();` and then reload the data using following code, still same error:

```
session.flush();
session.get(Student.class, student1.getStudentId());
System.out.println("Reading Clob : " + student1.getSearchProfileText().getCharacterStream());
```

OBSERVATION 2:

Even if I fetch a record containing CLOB data using Hibernate criteria and put a restriction against the CLOB column, I can't access CLOB data after fetching the record. I think, it is a BUG in 3.6.10 Final !!!

Please help to get rid of this error.. I have tried all related topics on this but no success yet :(

Answer (score 0):

Since you are reading the `getSearchProfileText` object from the `same object instance`, its not able to do so because pointer is at the end after setting the value. I think you need to reload the object before your read it e.g.

```
    Serializable  id = session.save(student1);
    //commit the transaction
    Student student = session.get(Student.class, id);
    System.out.println("Reading Clob :: " 
                           + student.getSearchProfileText().getCharacterStream());
```

Comment: Yes, you are correct. However, I can't use flush() to synchronize the new Student record and then reload same record for reading the Clob object again. :( Can you help on this ? How can I read the same Clob object after saving it into hibernate session before committing the session. Remember it works with Hibenrate 3.2.5 but not with Hibernate 3.6.10.

Comment: @DhruboBhattacharjee: How are you creating the CLOB? Can't you use the same source to refer wherever it is required?

Comment: creating CLOB using session.getLobHelper().createClob(String)... and no even I can't access same clob object after saving the record. pointer is not getting rest to first position. I am currently working with getSubString() API. Let me know if there is any way to use getCharecterStream() API.

Comment: @DhruboBhattacharjee Since you are already having the `String` which you used to create the `Clob`, why don't you use the same String to get the stream/reader e.g. `new InputStreamReader(new ByteArrayInputStream(string.getBytes()));`?

Comment: Yes, that is an option, however there could be long complex methods hierarchy where I don't want to pass the string every time as method parameter. I am just wondering why I can't access the CLOB data after doing a flush and reloading of the record !!! In addition, even if you fetch a record containing CLOB data using Hibernate criteria and its restriction against the CLOB column, you can't access CLOB data after fetching the record... is it not BUG ?!!!

Comment: @DhruboBhattacharjee: You mean, even after fresh read, you are not able to read the data? I am bit confused about your `flush`. If you are done with the transaction, then data is already committed, and you should be reloading. If it's not, it means you are not with the transaction itself and you are reading your own object. I won't consider this as bug as it your are trying to read (as outstream) your input (as inputstream) itself as output which doesn't sound as right design pattern any way.

Comment: Please consider second observation, when I just want to fetch a record using restriction against CLOB column and then try to access the CLOB data using getCharacterStream() API. If I do so, I am getting above mentioned exception. You can try it yourself. 

And, regarding your comment,  whether I am accessing same data in same session or not, Hibernate session should allow me to access any data in session. is not it ?